# Loop outputting first and last inputs data

Tags: php

**Problem**

So, I have a input field were users can input a teams leader's first and last names, and then can click on a "add members" to add as many team members as they want to add. My problem is that when I cycle through the input data in a foreach loop and output the data, it only outputs the first and last inputs data, and all the inputs data.

**Example**

Lets say the user inputs:

- The leader

  - Rick
- The members

  - Jessica
  - Danial
  - Krisha

This is what is being outputted:

```
Rick

Krisha
```

But I want this to be outputted:

```
Rick

Jessica

Danial

Krisha
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php

    require '../connect.php';

    foreach ($_POST as $name) {
        echo $name . "<br>";
    }

 ?>
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="add-team">

     <h2 class="toggle-inputs">Add Team <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>

     <form class="inputs" action="server/add/add-team.php" method="post">
           <a href="JavaScript:void(0)">Add A Member</a>

           <div class="members">
                <input type="text" name="leader-name" placeholder="* Leaders First and Last Name...">
           </div>
           <button type="submit" name="add-team"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Team</button>
     </form>
</div> <!-- END OF ADD-TEAM -->
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
// MAIN
function main() {
    $(".add-team a").on("click", addTeamMember);
}

var countOfMembers = 1; // we keep track of how many members we are adding

// ADD TEAM MEMBER
function addTeamMember() {
    countOfMembers += 1; 
    $(".members").append("<input type='text' name='member-name" + countOfMembers + "' placeholder='* Members First and Last Name...'>");
}

// LOAD
$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because all of the inputs for team members have the name set to `member-name`, so the last one overrides the previous ones. Your javascript function `addTeamMember` has to be changed so that when it adds new inputs, it uses a different name for each of them. Here is a way to do it (untested):

```
var countOfMembers = 1; // we keep track of how many members we are adding

// ADD TEAM MEMBER
function addTeamMember() {
    countOfMembers += 1; 
    $(".members").append("<input type='text' name='member-name" + countOfMembers + "' 
    placeholder='* Members First and Last Name...'>");
}
```

This way, the name of of the input for the first member will be `member-name-1`, for the second it will be `member-name-2`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Hey bud MicSoki is correct.  You want to make name='member-name'  into an array as follows name='member-name[]'  Then, loop through them all in your PHP to add them to your database

```
$leaderName = $_POST["leader-name"];
$memberName = $_POST["member-name"];
for ($i=0; $i<count($memberName); $i++){
    $anotherMember = $memberName[$i];
    // insert anotherMember into database using prepared statement
    }
```

You were only getting the leader name and the last member name in you PHP cause your post consisted of the leader name and the last member name (you kept over writing each member name variable so you only ended up with the last one).  That'w why you need to use an array.  Also, when you retrieve the post data, you have to recognize leader-name and all the member-names are in two separate categories.